# Evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{1\over n^5}$ up to the second decimal place

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am trying to evaluate
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{1\over n^5}$$
up to the second decimal place. While the series is convergent, I have no idea how to construct such a bound, preferably using basic properties of series and sequences. Any hints?

Comment: Not directly what you want, but you could take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_Riemann_zeta_function#.CE.B6.285.29).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If we truncate the sum $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^5}$ to $\sum\limits_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n^5}$, we can bound the error term as

$$\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^5} \le 
\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac{1}{(N+1)^2(n-1)n(n+1)}
= \frac{1}{2(N+1)^2}\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{(n-1)n} - \frac{1}{n(n+1)}\right)$$
The last piece is a telescoping sum. This gives us
$$\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^5} \le \frac{1}{2N(N+1)^3}$$
For $N = 3$, this is $$\frac{1}{2\cdot 3\cdot 4^3} = \frac{1}{384} \approx 0.00260416666666666$$
Keeping the first three term already give us an estimate accurate to two decimal places.
More precisely,

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^5} = \zeta(5) = 1.03692775514337\cdots
\quad\leftrightarrow\quad
\sum_{n=1}^3 \frac{1}{n^5} = \frac{8051}{7776}\approx 1.035365226337449
$$

The actual error $\approx 0.001562528805921337$ and we only over estimate the error for $67\%$. Not bad for such a simple approach.

**Update**

If one knows integration, a easier to deduce error bound is given by integral test.
For our case, $\frac{1}{x^5}$ is a monotonic decreasing function, this leads to

$$\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^5} \le \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty
\int_{n-1}^{n}\frac{dx}{x^5} = \int_N^\infty \frac{dx}{x^5} = \frac{1}{4N^4}$$

For $N = 3$, this give us an error bound $\frac{1}{324} \approx 0.00308641975308642$ compatible to what have get by a more elementary but harder to figure out approaches.

For this particular problem, there is actually another improvement one should know.
Notice $\displaystyle\;\frac{d^2}{dx^2} \frac{1}{x^5} = \frac{30}{x^7} > 0$, $\displaystyle\;\frac{1}{x^5}\;$ is a convex function for $x > 0$. For all $n > 1$, we have

$$
\frac{1}{n^5} \le \int_{n-1/2}^{n+1/2} \frac{dx}{x^5}, \forall n >1
\quad\implies\quad
\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^5} \le 
\int_{N+1/2}^\infty \frac{dx}{x^5} = \frac{1}{4(N+\frac12)^4}$$

For $N = 3$, this leads to an error bound
$\frac{1}{4(7/2)^4} = \frac{4}{2401} \approx 0.001665972511453561$
which over estimate only for $7\%$.

After one learn integration and convex function, if one see a similar problem
like this, make sure to check whether your function is convex and if possible, take advantage of that.

Comment: Brilliant use of telescoping series! (+1).  And happy holidays!  -Mark

Comment: @Dr.MV [Happy Holidays](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ycjg6qb7s5) ( with some polar/parametric magic :D )

Comment: @SimpleArt And you too!

Comment: @Dr.MV By convexity $\int_{n-1/2}^{n+1/2}\frac{dx}{x^5} = \int_0^{1/2}\left(\frac{1}{(n+x)^5}+\frac{1}{(n-x)^5}\right)dx \ge \int_0^{1/2}\frac{2}{n^5} dx = \frac{1}{n^5}$. If $\frac{1}{n^5} \le \int_{n-1}^n \frac{dx}{x^5}$, the integral systematically overestimate $\frac{1}{n^5}$. If one switch the limit to $n\pm 1/2$, this get rid of the bias but no longer guarantee it is a upper bound. convexity is a simple check one can use to restore the bound.  if convexity is available, it give us a much tighter estimate.

Comment: @Dr.MV plug $N = 3$ into the formula, the correct value for $\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^5}$ is around $0.001562528805921337$, my expression gives $0.001665972511453561$, $\frac{1}{N^5} + \frac{1}{4(N+1)^4}$ gives $0.00509178883744856$.

Answer (score 11):

**HINT:**

Recall from [The Integral Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence#Proof)

$$\int_N^{M+1} \frac{1}{x^5}\,dx\le \sum_{n=N}^M\frac{1}{n^5}\le \frac{1}{N^5}+\int_N^M \frac{1}{x^5}\,dx$$

Comment: The problem here is that I'm looking for a low-tech solution. The material I'm going over hasn't covered integration at all, so my guess is there has to be a "trick" answer to that.

Comment: @Zelazny Technically, the integrals require not tech here, as they are quite elementary, given a bit of calculus magic.

Answer (score 7):

We may use Beuker-like integrals, for instance. If we set $\zeta(5)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^5}$, we have:
$$ 24\,\zeta(5) = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log(x)^4}{1-x}\,dx,\qquad \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^4\log(x)^4}{1-x}\,dx =  -\frac{257875}{10368}+24\,\zeta(5)\tag{1}$$
but the function $g(x)=\frac{x^4\log^4(x)}{1-x}$ is non-negative and bounded by $\frac{1}{60}$ on the interval $(0,1)$, hence:
$$ \zeta(5) \approx \frac{257875}{248832}= \color{red}{1.036}3417888\ldots \tag{2} $$

Comment: If the OP found @Dr.MV's answer too complicated, yours is surely overkill.

Comment: When I meet a problem along my road, I always like to kill it, burn it then put it in a strong acid.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Now that was funny!!  Happy holidays Jack

Comment: For the first time in my life I am proud to have found a solution that works better than yours! I'll go get drunk!

Comment: @AlexM. And you might have just written a funnier comment than Jack's. Two for two; so perhaps order doubles.  And happy holidays.

Comment: Happy holidays to you too, @Dr.MV, even though we are still a few days away from them. Nice community we've got here!

Comment: @AlexM. I suppose if the integral test is too high tech, than the Euler-Maclaurin summation formula would be right out.

Comment: @Dr.MV, you might try adding it as an edit to your post, after all - for future readers, if not for the OP. Meanwhile, I'll accept your challenge and try to come up with a solution based on the Poisson summation formula or the Plancherel formula.

Comment: Go get drunk (and a little blind) by staring at this [holiday spirit](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ycjg6qb7s5) for a while.

Comment: @SimpleArt Best to avoid viewing if one has indulged in strong acid :-)

Comment: @Bungo If its too much, I recommend stopping one of the parameters or setting the step to larger numbers.  :D

Answer (score 3):

If you're allowed to use the fact that $\sum1/n^2=\pi^2/6$, you can calculate when the tail of $\sum1/n^2$ is less than $0.01$, say

$$\sum_{n\geq m}1/n^2<0.01$$

Then $S=\sum_{n\geq m} 1/n^5$ is also less than $0.01$ .

Comment: Your idea is nice, but I am sure that the OP may not use that result. Anyway, the same idea but with a geometric series instead of $\sum \frac 1 {n^2}$ (which is also easier to evaluate and quicker to converge) solves the problem at a somewhat more elementary level, as desired by the OP.

Comment: That's true, I like your suggestion. Will edit.

Comment: Better leave is as it is - otherwise it will resemble my answer too much.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri How do you plan to estimate the error of the truncated series for $\zeta(2)$?

Comment: @Dr.MV If you know the value in the limit, just take the limit value and subtract partial sums.

Comment: I see.  So, you would pursue with numerical analysis and find a number $N$ such that $\pi^2/6-\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{n^2}$ is within the desired tolerance.  That works.

Comment: The second method doesn't work since the geometric series converges much more rapidly than the series representation for $\zeta(5)$.

Comment: @Dr.MV Oops, that's completely right. We actually need $1/n^5$ to be less than the term of the tail we're comparing to. I guess I was overexcited by Alex M.'s suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

**Alternating Series**
$$
\begin{align}
&1+\frac1{2^5}+\frac1{3^5}+\frac1{4^5}+\frac1{5^5}+\frac1{6^5}+\dots\\
&\phantom{1}-\frac{2}{2^5}\phantom{+\frac1{3^5}1}-\frac2{4^4}\phantom{+\frac1{5^5}1}-\frac{2}{6^5}\tag*{$\left(-\frac2{2^5}\text{times the line above}\right)$}\\
=&1-\frac1{2^5}+\frac1{3^5}-\frac1{4^5}+\frac1{5^5}-\frac1{6^5}+\dots\\
\end{align}
$$
Thus, the alternating sum is $\frac{15}{16}$ of the non-alternating sum. By the [Alternating Series Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test), the error at any point is less than the first unused term. Thus to get two digits of precision, we only need to go up to, but not including, $\frac1{3^5}=\frac1{243}$. That is,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^5}
&\approx\frac{16}{15}\left(1-\frac1{2^5}\right)\\
&=1.0333333
\end{align}
$$
to within $\frac{16}{15}\frac1{243}=0.0043896$. In fact, the Alternating Series Test says that
$$
1.0333333\le\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^5}\le1.0377229
$$
where the upper bound is
$$
\frac{16}{15}\left(1-\frac1{2^5}+\frac1{3^5}\right)
$$
The next lower bound is
$$
\frac{16}{15}\left(1-\frac1{2^5}+\frac1{3^5}-\frac1{4^5}\right)=1.0366812
$$
So now we can say that
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{1.0366812\le\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^5}\le1.0377229}
$$
Thus, to two decimal places, the sum would be $1.04$.

---

**Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula**

Using the [Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula):
$$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{k=1}^{100}\frac1{k^5}-\left[-\frac1{4n^4}+\frac1{2n^5}-\frac5{12n^6}+\frac7{24n^8}-\frac1{2n^{10}}+\frac{11}{8n^{12}}-\frac{65}{12n^{14}}\right]_{n=100}\\[9pt]
&=1.036927755143369926331365486457
\end{align}
$$
The next term is $\frac{691}{24n^{16}}$, so the error is on the order of $3\times10^{-31}$.

---

**Estimating the Error with Bernoulli's Inequality**

Using the Alternating Series Test is pretty easy, but we can also use [Bernoulli's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli's_inequality) to estimate the error. For $p\ge1$,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1{n^p}-\frac1{(n+1)^p}
&=\frac1{n^p}\left[1-\frac1{\left(1+\frac1n\right)^p}\right]\\
&\ge\frac1{n^p}\left[1-\frac1{1+\frac pn}\right]\\
&=\frac1{n^p}\frac{\frac pn}{1+\frac pn}\\
&\ge\frac1{n^p}\frac{\frac pn}{\left(1+\frac1n\right)^p}\\[4pt]
&=\frac p{n(n+1)^p}\\[8pt]
&\ge\frac p{(n+1)^{p+1}}
\end{align}
$$
The first two inequalities are due to Bernoulli's inequality, the last is simply because $n\lt n+1$. Using this inequality, we get that
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^{p+1}}-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{k^{p+1}}
&=\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac1{k^{p+1}}\\
&=\sum_{k=n}^\infty\frac1{(k+1)^{p+1}}\\
&\le\frac1p\sum_{k=n}^\infty\left(\frac1{k^p}-\frac1{(k+1)^p}\right)\\
&=\frac1{p\,n^p}
\end{align}
$$
Thus, the error in approximating the infinite sum using $n$ terms is at most $\frac1{4n^4}$. Therefore, the error in
$$
\sum_{k=1}^3\frac1{k^5}=1.0353652
$$
is at most $\frac1{4\cdot3^4}=0.0030864$. That is,
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{1.0353652\le\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^5}\le1.0384516}
$$
Thus, to two decimal places, the sum would be $1.04$.

Comment: would the downvoter care to comment? I first answered using the Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula, which gives far more digits than I wrote. When I noted that the OP wanted simpler methods, I included an approximation that uses alternating series.

Comment: I have extended the computation so that now it shows all the digits that one might expect from using $n=100$. This invalidates the part of my previous comment which says that the EMSF "gives far more digits than I wrote".

Comment: I have added a couple more terms to the Alternating Series approach to get the sum to two decimal places, rather than just two digits of precision $\left(\pm\frac1{200}\right)$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $N$ be such that $\sum \limits _{k \ge 2^N} ^\infty \frac 1 {n^5} \le \epsilon$. Notice that

$$\sum _{k \ge 2^N} ^\infty \frac 1 {n^5} \le \sum _{m \ge 0} \ \sum _{k = 2^{N+m}} ^{2^{N+m+1}-1} \frac 1 {n^5} \le \sum _{m \ge 0} \ \sum _{k = 2^{N+m}} ^{2^{N+m+1}-1} \frac 1 {(2^{N+m})^5} = \sum _{m \ge 0} \frac {2^{N+m}} {(2^{N+m})^5} = \sum _{m \ge 0} \frac 1 {(2^{N+m})^4} = \\
\frac 1 {2^{4N}} \sum _{m \ge 0} \frac 1 {2^{4m}} = \frac 1 {2^{4N}} \frac 1 {1 - \frac 1 {16}} = \frac 1 {15} \frac 1 {16^{N-1}} .$$

It follows that in order to have the inequality that we have begun with, it is sufficient to impose that $\frac 1 {15} \frac 1 {16^{N-1}} \le \epsilon$, which means $16^{N-1} \ge \frac 1 {15 \epsilon}$, whence $N-1 \ge \log_{16} \frac 1 {15 \epsilon} = -\log_{16} (15\epsilon) = -\frac 1 4 \log_2 (15 \epsilon)$, so $N = \left[ 1 -\frac 1 4 \log_2 (15 \epsilon) \right] + 1$, where $[x]$ denotes the integer part of $x$ (the "floor" function, as some call it).

Now just choose $\epsilon = 10^{-3}$ (because you want the first 2 decimal places to be exact) in order to get $N = \left[ 1 -\frac 1 4 \log_2 (15 \cdot 10^{-3}) \right] + 1 = 3$. This means that

$$\sum _{n=1} ^{2^3-1} \frac 1 {n^5} = 1.\color{red}{03}6849\dots$$

has the first 2 decimal places correct.

Answer (score 2):

Considering the telescoping sum

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \left[ \frac{1}{n^2(n-1)^2}-\frac{1}{n^2(n+1)^2} \right]=\frac{1}{4}$$

Also $$\frac{1}{n^2(n-1)^2}-\frac{1}{n^2(n+1)^2}=\frac{4}{n^{5}}+O\left( \frac{1}{n^7} \right)$$

\begin{align*}
  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^5} &=
  1+\frac{1}{16}+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}
  \left[
    \frac{1}{n^5}-\frac{1}{4n^2(n-1)^2}+\frac{1}{4n^2(n+1)^2}
  \right] \\
  &= \frac{17}{16}-\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{2n^2-1}{n^5(n^2-1)^2} \\
  &\approx \frac{17}{16}-\sum_{n=2}^{\color{red}{3}} \frac{2n^2-1}{n^5(n^2-1)^2} \\
  &= 1.03710 \ldots \\
  &= \zeta(5)-0.000173 \ldots
\end{align*}

**Error bound**

\begin{align*}
  E(N) &=\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty} \frac{2n^2-1}{n^5(n^2-1)^2} \\ &<
  \sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty} \frac{2}{n^3(n^2-1)^2} \\
  &< \sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty} \int_{n}^{n+1} \frac{2}{x^3(x^2-1)^2} \, dx \\
  &= \frac{2N^2-1}{N^2(N^2-1)}-\ln \frac{N^4}{(N^2-1)^2}
\end{align*}

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
N & E(N)< \\
\hline
2 & 0.007969 \ldots \\
3 & 0.000545 \ldots \\
4 & 0.000089 \ldots \\
5 & 0.000022 \ldots \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

That's why $N=\color{red}{3}$ is enough for $2$ decimal places.

Comment: How do you know to put $3$ (in red) as an upper bound for the summation index? After all, that is the crux of the problem. And using $\approx$ is not rigorous, how do you know that the first 2 decimal places are not affected?

Comment: Updated the error estimates.

Comment: Nice, but you use integration too, which the OP hasn't studied.

Comment: I think the course he/she taken now has not covered integration yet, at least he/she knows what's integration.  By the way, I'd like to use Euler Maclaurin summation formula if I were him/her.

Answer (score 1):

For $n>1$ we have $$1/n^5+1/(n+1)^5+1/(n+2)^5+...<$$ $$<\frac {1}{n^3}\left(\frac {1}{(n-1)n}+\frac {1}{n(n+1)}+\frac {1}{(n+1)(n+2)}+...\right)=$$ $$=\frac {1}{n^3}\left((\frac {1}{n-1}-\frac {1}{n})+(\frac {1}{n}-\frac {1}{n+1})+(\frac {1}{n+1}-\frac {1}{n+2})+...\right)=$$ $$=\frac {1}{n^3(n-1)}$$ because the sum of the first $k$ terms of the last infinite series above is $\frac {1}{n-1}-\frac {1}{n-1+k}.$

This is not as sharp an upper bound as can be found by deeper methods. We have $1.036<\sum_{n=1}^{n=5}n^{-5}<1.037$ and the sum of the remaining terms is less than $1/(6^3\cdot 5)=1/1080.$ So the sum rounded to 2 decimal places is $1.04$

Answer (score 1):

The OP indicated a preference for approaches that establish the first two decimal places of $\sum{1\over n^5}$ using only basic properties of series and sequences.  Here are two approaches.  The first uses a telescoping series.  The second uses the geometric series ${1\over2}+{1\over4}+{1\over8}+\cdots=1$.

**First approach (telescoping series)**

The first two terms give

$$1+{1\over2^5}=1.03125$$

In order to conclude that $1.03$ is accurate to the second decimal place (rounding down), it suffices to show that

$${1\over3^5}+{1\over4^5}+{1\over5^5}+\cdots\lt0.00875$$

To show this, we'll make use of the telescoping series

$${1\over4\cdot5}+{1\over5\cdot6}+{1\over6\cdot7}+\cdots=\left({1\over4}-{1\over5}\right)+\left({1\over5}-{1\over6}\right)+\left({1\over6}-{1\over7}\right)+\cdots={1\over4}$$

Crude inequalities such as $5^5\gt5^3\cdot4\cdot5$ and $6^5\gt5^3\cdot5\cdot6$, etc., allow us to conclude

$${1\over3^5}+{1\over4^5}+{1\over5^5}+\cdots\lt{1\over3^5}+{1\over4^5}+{1\over5^3}\left({1\over4\cdot5}+{1\over5\cdot6}+{1\over6\cdot7}+\cdots \right)={1\over243}+{1\over1024}+{1\over125\cdot4}\lt{1\over200}+{1\over1000}+{1\over500}=0.008$$

which indeed is less than $0.00875$.

Remark:  If you want to show that the sum is closer to $1.04$ than $1.03$, it's enough to note that ${1\over3^5}={1\over243}\gt{1\over250}=0.004$, which when added to $1.03125$, gives $1.03525$.

**Second approach (geometric series)**:

$$100\sum_{n=1}^\infty{1\over n^5}=100+{96+4\over32}+{100\over3^5}+\cdots=103+{1\over8}+{100\over243}+100\left({1\over4^5}+{1\over5^5}+\cdots \right)$$

To show that $\sum{1\over n^5}\approx1.03$, it suffices to show $100\sum{1\over n^5}-103\lt1$.

$$\begin{align}
100\sum{1\over n^5}-103
&={1\over8}+{100\over243}+100\left({1\over4^5}+{1\over5^5}+{1\over6^5}+{1\over7^5} \right)+100\left({1\over8^5}+{1\over9^5}+\cdots+{1\over15^5} \right)+100\left({1\over16^5}+{1\over17^5}+\cdots+{1\over31^5} \right)+\cdots\\
&\lt{1\over8}+{1\over2}+{400\over4^5}+128{8\over8^5}+128{16\over16^5}+\cdots\\
&={1\over8}+{1\over2}+{400\over1024}+{2^7\over2^{12}}+{2^7\over2^{16}}+{2^7\over2^{20}}+\cdots\\
&\lt{1\over8}+{1\over2}+{1\over4}+{1\over2^4}+{1\over2^5}+{1\over2^6}+\cdots\\
&=1
\end{align}$$